# How to use FILTER IN in dotnetrdf

Tags: c#, dotnetrdf

I want to use the "FILTER IN" Filter in dotnetRdf, but I don`t get it running.

My Query is below, but I do not have an idea what to enter in the the "In" Method. I want to have there a list of URIs.

```
var queryBuilder =
                QueryBuilder
                .Select("name")
                .Where(
                    (triplePatternBuilder) =>
                    {
                        triplePatternBuilder
                            .Subject("person")
                            .Predicate("exp:called")
                            .Object("name");
                    })
                .Filter(builder => builder.Variable(name).In());
```

**EDIT**

IriExpression does not work

[image: IriExpression does not work]

Answer (score 2):

The `In()` method just takes one or more SparqlExpression arguments. So you can use an `IriExpression` for a list of IRI constants:

```cs
using System;
using VDS.RDF.Query.Builder.Expressions;

namespace VDS.RDF.Query.Builder
{
    public class FilterInTests
    {
        public void TestFilterInUris()
        {
            var b = QueryBuilder
                .Select("name")
                .Where(
                    t =>
                        t.Subject("person")
                            .PredicateUri("exp:called")
                            .Object("name"))
                .Filter(fb => fb.Variable("name").In(
                    new IriExpression(new ConstantTerm(new UriNode(null, new Uri("http://example.com/p1")))),
                    new IriExpression(new ConstantTerm(new UriNode(null, new Uri("http://example.com/p2"))))));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have an error, because URI can`t be converted to ISparqlExpression

Comment: Did you wrap the URI in a `new  IriExpression()`? That fragment of code I posted does compile and run ok for me

Comment: Yes I am sure, that I did it exactly the same way. I tried it with older versions as well.  Do you use System.Uri or is there maybe another one?

Comment: It is just the standard System.Uri class - that is really strange that it doesn't work for you. Are you getting an error when compiling or when running the code?  Can you copy and paste the error message you are seeing please...it might help me to figure out what is going on! If it is easier for you, please open a ticket at https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/issues. Thanks!

Comment: The error is while compiling: Converting "System.Uri" to  "VDS.RDF.Query.Expressions.ISparqlExpression" not possible.

Comment: That does sound like you are missing the `new IriExpression()` wrapper around each `Uri` - you cannot add a `System.Uri` instance directly to the parameters to the `In()` method, you have to pass in a list of `ISparqlExpression` instances. The `IriExpression` class implements that interface for URIs.
I've updated the example code to show my full source code including the imports. This does compile using dotNetRDF 2.6. Can you cut and paste this code and see if it works for you?

Comment: I edited my question with a screenshot. My IriExpression wants an ISparqlExpression. I tried with .net core and .net. The same error

Comment: Ah, my bad! My answer was using an internal constructor on the IriExpression class which is why it wouldn't compile for you. (Lesson learned...use a new project to test out sample code!).
I've updated my answer to a version that uses the public constructor on IriExpression and I'll raise a bug to make the internal constructor public in the next release. Apologies for the confusion!

Comment: This is the ticket for the feature enhancement: https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/issues/332

Comment: Better :) but I have to mention that with UriNode there is the same problem, it is also an internal constructor, why it still does not work. But at least with stringNodes it works :)